# Bash - Find several specific folders in a directory and its sbdirectories and rename these specific folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I just started to study Bash. I want to do a script to find some specific folders in a directory and its subdirectories and if it exist, rename it into the same folder where we have found it. The same specific folder can be in some subdirectories.

I use this:

```
file=`find . -name a`
if [ -d $file ]
then
rename 's/a/b/' $file
fi
```

But don't work. Is there anyway to do this process?

Thanks.

Finally, i solved the problem with this:

```
find . -name "a" -type d -execdir rename 's/a/b/' {} \; &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with oneliner:

`find . -name "a" -type d -execdir rename 's/a/b/' {} \;`

The parameter to name might be regex.
With `-type d` it will find all directories.
`-execdir` changes to a matching item's directory and then executes the `rename` command, passing the filename of the item at hand as an argument (`{}`).

Comment: Sorry, mistakenly used -type f instead of -type d :)

Comment: i've never found  find ... -exec  terribly useful.  why?   wouldn't you like to see the candidate list before you mangle it?   so ... find * -name a -type d; then repeat the find ...  | awk '{ o=$1; sub("/\/a\//", "/b/", o) printf("mv %s %s\n", $1, o)}' ... untested.  rename?  not on Mac OS X, must be linux?

Comment: I usually do that w/o -exec, it's easier for simpler operations, but in this case your method is rocking also.

Comment: Thanks, finally i used this: find . -name "a" -type d -execdir rename 's/a/b/' {} \; &>/dev/null

Comment: @MartyMcGowan: `-exec` is the most efficient way to execute a command for _each_ matching file (`exec … {} \;`) or to execute a single command for (typically) _all_ matching files (`-exec … {} +`). To perform a dry run, simply prepend `echo` to the command. Debian-based Linux distros, e.g., Ubuntu, have the `rename` utility used here, which is Perl-based and very flexible: http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/. Other Linux distros, such as Fedora, have a different, far less powerful `rename` utility, from the util-linux package. BSD-based systems, including OSX, have neither.

Comment: @mklement0 edited. Good to know you found the answer that suits for you and solves your problem.